# Possible to limit internal link search to post types with Gutenberg editor?

Tags: custom-post-types, block-editor, links, linking

My site consists of posts and several custom post types, one of which is "articles" and it's for news aggregation. It generates quite a bit of posts per day and an unforeseen consequence is when I'm writing a blog or editing a page and want to link to another page or post (basically my own content), it's extremely hard as the search results is populated with the CPT "articles". So, I was curious if there was a hook or something to limit the post types the get searched? The closest plugin I could find is quite old (https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-internal-link-search/), but it's essentially what I'm looking for. I tried editing that plugin and making some adjustments, but I'm not a WordPress Pro and was unsuccessful.

Anyway, is there anyway to limit post types for internal link searching?

Thanks,
AJ

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not capable within Gutenberg as of now. There is an issue on the tracker that requests the ability to filter the internal links - https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/31496